# Kindle Fire : Content browsing

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I want to put the apk file into the Kindle Fire storage(through USB cable) and want to install it on the device. Any suggestions regarding how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sideload basically.

See this http://www.tested.com/news/feature/3179-how-to-sideload-android-apps-on-the-amazon-kindle-fire-in-3-steps/